# PHP fopen() on local file that DOES exist

Tags: php, linux, windows, fopen

Using php 5.2.17, on a Linux Server.  My office production machine is Windows7 Professional with Service Pack 1 installed.

Trying desperately -- and so far, in vain -- to get `fopen()` to find and open a .csv file on my local machine in order to import records to an existing MySQL database on the server. Consistently getting a "failed to open stream" error message.

Here is part of the code, with explanatory notes / server responses, including notes on what I have tried:

```
ini_set('track_errors', 1);   // Set just to make sure I was seeing all of the rrror codes
ini_set ('user_agent', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); // Tried after reading a note; no effect

error_reporting(E_ALL);            // Again, just to make sure all error codes visible!
echo(get_include_path()."<br />"); // Initially returns: .:/usr/local/php5/lib/php
set_include_path("C:\SWSRE\\");    // Have tried with BOTH forward and backslashes, BOTH single and doubled, in every conceivable combination!
ini_set('safe_mode_include_dir',"C:\SWSRE");  // Ditto here for slashes!
echo(get_include_path()."<br />");  //NOW echoes "C:\SWSRE\"
clearstatcache();  // Just in case this was a problem -- added after reading note @ php.net

$file = "Individuals.txt";   // This absolutely DOES exist locally in C:\SWSRE\ (29Mb)
// Inserted following tests to see if it even SEES the file.  It does NOT.
if (file_exists("Individuals.txt")) {
    echo("File EXISTS!!!<br />");
} else {
    echo("File does NOT exist!<br />");  // Echoes "File does NOT exist!"
}
if(is_readable($file)) {
    echo 'readable' ;
} else { 
    echo 'NOT readable!<br />';  // Echoes "NOT readable!"

}
if(is_writable($file)) {
    echo 'writable ' ;
} else { 
    echo 'NOT writable!<br />';  // Echoes "NOT readable!"
}

$handle = fopen("Individuals.txt", "r+", TRUE);
```

Here are the final PHP error messages:

> Warning: fopen(Individuals.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/b/u/r/burtsweeto/html/ADREImport.php on line 145
>   array(4) { ["type"]=> int(2) ["message"]=> string(118) "fopen(Individuals.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory" ["file"]=> string(56) "/home/content/b/u/r/burtsweeto/html/ADREImport.php" ["line"]=> int(145) }

Finally, I have tried putting the file up in the directory where the PHP script is running; and it does work exactly correctly there!  I'm just trying to minimize ongoing headaches for the end-user by not having to upload a huge file before doing the import.

Any suggestions that I have not tried?

Comment: what is the file permission ?

Comment: `file_exists()` doesn't take include path into consideration.

Comment: Having this exact same problem, in a wordpress site. fopen() will only open a file if and only if the file is in the same directory as the functions.php file from which the fopen is being called.

Answer (score 1):

Add the full path to `$file`, like this:

```
$file = "C:\\SWSRE\\Individuals.txt";
```

`set_include_path()` and the `ini_set()` do what they sound like; they adjust *include* paths, which is not the same as *all* paths. `file_exists()` expects either an absolute path or a path relative to the PHP file calling it. It is not affected by `set_include_path()` or `ini_set('safe_mode_include_dir',...)`

Comment: I did try this before and just now AGAIN.  It still gives me the same errors regarding is_readable() and is_writable().  (@ShivanRaptor) As to permissions, since the file is on my local machine for which I am logged in as Administrator, doesn't that take care of file permissions?